# Mapping numeric keypad keys in vim

Tags: vim, xterm

I'm unable to get this mapping to work in vim inside an xterm terminal.

```
:map <k0> :echo 'Hello'<CR>
```

I can get the same mapping to work fine in gvim. If I issue the above command in vim on a terminal, it accepts it, and it shows up correctly when I type `:map`. But in normal mode, if I press the <kbd>0</kbd> keypad key, a "0" shows up on the status line, and then disappears with the next keypress.

I'm using the vim that came with Fedora 14 if that matters, and a plain xterm. The keypad keys work fine in insert mode, both with numlock on and off.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
xterm*appkeypadDefault: false
```

and relaunch xterm.

The "Application Keypad Mode" is likely the reason of your troubles.

But I don't think you should do what you are doing. In `--NORMAL--` mode, numeric input is used to indicate "count" like in `4dd`. Mapping numbers to other commands is going to get you into troubles fast.

You should add a `xterm` tag to your question.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but this didn't work. Also, 'false' is the default value for xterm*appkeypadDefault as shown in the xterm man page.

I've used vim for everything for over a decade, and I've never used my *keypad* to specify repetitions (not having to take my hands off the home position is one of the advantages of vim). So I'm okay with mapping the keypad.

Answer (score 0):

There's some ambiguity in the question, which may indicate the actual problem.  vim accepts that binding for `k0` supposing that it is a function key.

Most keyboards that you'll see number function-keys starting at **`1`**, and a few terminal descriptions equate function-key 1 to `k0`, a few equate it `k0` to function-key 10.  It's also *possible* that someone assumes that is part of the numeric keypad, but unlikely (since the keypad uses different character sequences than the function keys).

That's assuming you used a terminal description that knows about the function keys.  The vt100 terminal description doesn't do that, since vt100's had no function keys (other than <kbd>PF1</kbd> through <kbd>PF4</kbd> which are or aren't depending who you talk to).  But if you had `TERM=vt100`, then *some* of the numeric keypad could be recognized on the basis of the terminal description (see for instance the lengthy comment above the [`vt100+fnkeys` description](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-vt100_fnkeys)).

It's not in `TERM=xterm`, however.

What you're overlooking is that vim (helpfully perhaps) amends the terminal description using its built-in termcaps.  It recognizes <kbd>PF1</kbd>, etc. using table entries like this:

```
{K_XF1,             IF_EB("\033O*P", ESC_STR "O*P")},
{K_XF2,             IF_EB("\033O*Q", ESC_STR "O*Q")},
{K_XF3,             IF_EB("\033O*R", ESC_STR "O*R")},
{K_XF4,             IF_EB("\033O*S", ESC_STR "O*S")},
```

But there are no entries for the numbered keys; there's no `"\033O*p"` for the **`0`** key.

If vim has (in the terminal description) the `k0`, and you haven't mapped it to anything, vim will treat it as a literal **`0`**.  The same happens with `k1`, etc., in effect treating the function-keys and numeric keypad as the same thing.

For what it's worth, GNU `screen` does the same thing, but also for the numbered keys.  If I run `vim` inside `screen`, `vim` will see only the 0's.   A literal **`0`** in vim doesn't do much in command-mode.